# Create a last in first out table from a data set in r

Tags: r

I have a dataset with purcahse details and another dataset with current holding, how do i create a data set with LIFO process.

Purcahse data set

```
Date            Store        Count
10/10/2001       S1           10
15/10/2001       S2            5
```

Holding data set

```
8
```

Final Data set - required format

```
Date            Store        Count
10/10/2001       S1            3
15/10/2001       S2            5
```

Comment: Maybe [this package](https://github.com/paulponcet/flifo) can help you